# Given a dom element, how could I flatten it in jquery and/or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cross-browser

Let's say I get an element from the dom:

```
[<div id="generic-wrapper"> ... </div>]
```

How could I flatten it to include all elements inside?

EDIT: "generic-wrapper" is an arbitrary id, it could be anything. It could also be nested, as in wrappers within wrappers.

EDIT2: I want the final array to include all of the content of the original array, just flattened. This includes the wrapper. Is there a systematic way to construct and iterate through an array such as the one I am describing? Thanks again and apologies for the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by "Flatten" ?

Comment: the element "wrapper" containers other elements. Instead of an array containing only wrapper, I want it to contain all elements inside wrapper, and any elements inside those.

Comment: Do you want the returned array to include the wrapper element?

Answer (score 5):

Select them all at once:

```
var $allElements = $("#wrapper,#wrapper *")
```

I'm not sure if you want to exclude the wrapper element itself, but if so just use `"#wrapper *"`.

Comment: Or `$( '#wrapper' ).find( '*' ).andSelf()` to avoid having to write the ID-name twice.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - I _like_ repeating myself. I _like_ repeating myself.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

'Simple' solution:

```
var domElements = [<div id="generic-wrapper">...</div>];

$.merge( domElements, $(domElements).find('*'));
```

---

Better solution:

It sounds like what you're trying to do is, given an array of dom elements, add each of their descendants to the array. If you're using jQuery for the intended DOM manipulation, you should just **select them directly** (*as shown in code sample below*). This returns a jQuery object, which has an underlying array structure that you can use for basic array-indexing. If you need to get a true array, you can use the object's [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) method. The jQuery object is typically more useful though, since you can manipulate all matched elements easily (and you can also iterate over them using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)).

Select `#wrapper` and all of its descendants (if id is stored in a variable, replace `'#wrapper'` with `'#'` + the variable name.)

```
var domElements = $('#wrapper, #wrapper *');
```

Comment: that would exclude the #wrapper itself !

Comment: @unloco True, didn't realize OP wanted to include that as well, question wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

An HTML string?

```
$('<div>').append($('#wrapper').clone()).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one where you don't have to know the id of the parent selector when you flatten the selection:

```
var x = $('selector for the parent element');
var y = x.add($('*', x));
```

How it works:

Let's say you had an html structure like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So the first line, `var x = $('#foo')` selects the wrapper.

The second line, `var y = x.add($('*', x))` will take your selection of the wrapper and add to it a recursive selection of every element contained inside the wrapper. The end result looks like this:

```
[<div id="foo">...</div>, <ul>...</ul>, <li></li>]
```

Comment: How do I do it if I am constructing jQuery object from HTML string instead of the HTML from page?

```
var html = '<div id="asc_div"><div id="rendered">' + data + '</div></div>';
    
    const $html = $(html); // now we have a jQuery object   
```

Comment: @Volatil3 you would just do `var $html = $('<div>stuff here</div>'); var $flattened = $html.add($('*', $html))`. This will select every element inside `$html` and append them all to the jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **vanilla JS** solution. It takes a DOM element and returns a list.

```
function flatten(element) {
    const elements = [];
    for (let child of element.childNodes) {
        if (child.childElementCount == 0)
            elements.push(child)
        else
            elements.push(...flatten(child));
    }
    return elements
}
```

For example, this would take a DOM object like:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <g>
      <polygon points="..."/>
      <polygon points="..."/>
    </g>
    <path d="..."/>
    <path d="..."/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And output:

```
[<polygon>, <polygon>, <path>, <path>]
```

Sidenote: If instead what you need is something that flattens the DOM object in-place, checkout [this gem](https://github.com/Jack000/SVGnest/blob/1248dc21efd3f90d1aa52ba5785e27e5217ed2c9/svgparser.js#L453).

Comment: How could it be done in jQuery?