# How to flatten element hierarchy with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to create a piece of code to take a jquery hierarchy and flatten it. I tried with regexps, string concatenation and element traversing. But I always end up with quirky code that doesn't do the job. Seems like I'm over my head and that I'm missing some key feature that simplifies the task.

Basically I want this:

```
<h3>
    AAA
    <p>
        BBB
        <p>
            <b>CCC</b>
        </p>
        DDD 
    </p>
    EEE
</h3>
```

To be transformed into this:

```
<h3>
    AAA
</h3>
<p>
    BBB
</p>
<p>
    <b>CCC</b>
</p>
<p>
    DDD
</p>
<h3>
    EEE
</h3>
```

I know my starting html isn't valid html, but I get that from user input and need to always keep a flat html hierarchy, except some tags, such as `<b>`, `<u>` and `<i>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*` selector like

```
var container = $('h3, h3 *')
```

You can filter it by using not

```
var container = $('h3, h3 *').not('b');
```

This will return a flattened array without the 'b' elements.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cjdb0vv8/1/)

[Given a dom element, how could I flatten it in jquery and/or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875684/given-a-dom-element-how-could-i-flatten-it-in-jquery-and-or-javascript)

Comment: With your example it's still not flattened. I get this html:
<h3>
    AAA
    <p>
        BBB
        </p><p>
            <b>CCC</b>
        </p>
        DDD 
    <p></p>
    EEE
</h3>